# Return both parent and child data from tables

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I'm using SQL Server 2012 and have 3 tables that I'm trying to pull data from: **Role**, **DependentRoles**, and **ActiveRole**:

[image: tables]

I need to return data for a given `Role` and data for any `DependentRole` for that role as well.  For instance, If the `Role` table has ids 1-15 and the `DependentRoles` table is populated like so:

[image]

we find that for the `RoleId` of 2, it has 2 `DependentRoles`; 4 & 5.  So if I want to find all the Roles that are assigned to a given role, my sql looks like this:

```
SELECT dr.*
FROM DependentRoles dr
INNER JOIN [Role] r ON dr.ChildRoleId = r.RoleId
INNER JOIN ActiveRole ar ON r.RoleId = ar.RoleId
WHERE ar.RoleId = 4
```

which produces this:

[image]

which tells me that Roles 5, 7, 9, 2, 10, 11, & 12 all depend on Role 4.  What I now need is to return the `RoleName` for the `ParentRoleId` and `ChildRoleId`.  I can't just add `r.RoleName` to the sql above because it returns just the Child RoleName, I need both.  I'd like to return `DependentRoleId`, `ParentRoleId`, `ParentRoleName`, `ChildRoleId`, `ChildRoleName`:

```
2    5   Role-E    4    Role-D 
3    7   Role-G    4    Role-D
5    9   Role-I    4    Role-D
8    2   Role-B    4    Role-D
```

I tried joining on the `Role` table again but to the `ParentRoleId` but I'm not getting any results for `ParentRoleName`:

```
SELECT dr.DependentRoleId, dr.ParentRoleId, r2.RoleName AS 'ParentRoleName', r.RoleId, r.RoleName AS 'ChildRoleName'
FROM DependentRoles dr
INNER JOIN [Role] r ON dr.ChildRoleId = r.RoleId
LEFT OUTER JOIN [Role] r2 ON dr.ParentRoleId = r.RoleId
INNER JOIN ActiveRole ar ON r.RoleId = ar.RoleId
WHERE ar.RoleId = 4
```

[image]

Any ideas on how I can get my desired results?  I must add that I will be translating this into linq statements so I'm trying to avoid CTE and other methods that I cannot convert.

Comment: Join tot he activeRole again on r2

Comment: Your last query seems reasonable. It joins according to both parent and child and renames the tables. Why do you use outer instead of inner join for all?

Comment: @DanteTheSmith - I tried that originally but it returns zero results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `OUTER JOIN` your `ON` is on r and not r2. Furthermore, if you always have a parent role, you should use `INNER JOIN` so something like this should work :

```
SELECT dr.DependentRoleId, dr.ParentRoleId AS 'ParentRoleID', 
r2.RoleName AS 'ParentRoleName', dr.ChildRoleId AS 'ChildRoleID' , r.RoleName AS 'ChildRoleName'
FROM DependentRoles dr
INNER JOIN [Role] r ON dr.ChildRoleId = r.RoleId
INNER JOIN [Role] r2 ON dr.ParentRoleId = r2.RoleId
INNER JOIN ActiveRole ar ON r.RoleId = ar.RoleId
WHERE ar.RoleId = 4
```